Menu pattern match not working based on Node value extended to child of child nodes
I have a code that return the menu structure based on node value eg. if input is parent1.child1 code will return the parent1.child1 json from mastermenu json.
Issue is structure can be extended to parent1.child1.sub-child1, but if parent1 having only single child and that child have multiple sub-childs then if I pass the pattern parent1.child1.sub-child1, it will return all the subchilds from master menu, and If i create new blank child2 under parent without any subchild code works as intended and return the correct output.
master-menu structure
{
  "menustructure": [
    {
      "child": [],
      "count": 1,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "home",
      "Menutext": "Home",
      "node": "home",
      "path": "https:pot",
      "rank": "1",
      "target": "embedded"
    },
    {
      "child": [
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "count": 33,
          "id": "configuration",
          "Menutext": "Configuration",
          "node": "Admin.configuration",
          "path": "/dc",
          "rank": "1",
          "child": [
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 54,
              "id": "a",
              "Menutext": "A",
              "node": "Admin.configuration.a",
              "path": "hdc",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 54,
              "id": "b",
              "Menutext": "B",
              "node": "Admin.configuration.b",
              "path": "hcd",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 54,
              "id": "c",
              "Menutext": "C",
              "node": "Admin.configuration.c",
              "path": "hdc",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 54,
              "id": "d",
              "Menutext": "D",
              "node": "Admin.configuration.d",
              "path": "hcd",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "count": 34,
          "id": "roles",
          "Menutext": "Roles",
          "node": "Admin.roles",
          "path": "/poter/admin/roles",
          "rank": "2"
        },
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "count": 35,
          "id": "menu",
          "Menutext": "Menu",
          "node": "Admin.menu",
          "path": "/poter/admin/menu",
          "rank": "3"
        },
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "count": 36,
          "id": "rmm",
          "Menutext": "RMM",
          "node": "Admin.rmm",
          "path": "/poter/admin/rmm",
          "rank": "4"
        },
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "count": 37,
          "id": "userroles",
          "Menutext": "URS",
          "node": "Admin.userroles",
          "path": "/poter/admin/userrol",
          "rank": "5"
        },
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "count": 38,
          "id": "logs",
          "Menutext": "Logs",
          "node": "Admin.logs",
          "path": "/poter/admin/logs",
          "rank": "5"
        }
      ],
      "count": 2,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "admin",
      "Menutext": "Admin",
      "node": "Admin",
      "path": "admin",
      "rank": "2",
      "target": ""
    },
    {
      "child": [],
      "count": 3,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "dc",
      "Menutext": "dc",
      "node": "dc",
      "path": "dc",
      "rank": "2",
      "target": "embedded"
    },
    {
      "child": [
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "count": 39,
          "id": "Tickets",
          "Menutext": "Tickets",
          "node": "l.Tickets",
          "path": "https:l",
          "rank": "1",
          "target": "embedded"
        }
      ],
      "count": 4,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "l",
      "Menutext": "L",
      "node": "l",
      "path": "l",
      "rank": "2",
      "target": ""
    },
    {
      "child": [],
      "count": 5,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "fu",
      "Menutext": "Fu",
      "node": "fu",
      "path": "/poter/fu",
      "rank": "2"
    },
    {
      "child": [],
      "count": 6,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "testingk",
      "Menutext": "testingk",
      "node": "testingk",
      "path": "/poter",
      "rank": "2"
    },
    {
      "child": [],
      "count": 7,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "ql",
      "Menutext": "sf",
      "node": "ql",
      "path": "ql",
      "rank": "2",
      "target": "embedded"
    },
    {
      "child": [],
      "count": 8,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "mp",
      "Menutext": "mp",
      "node": "mp",
      "path": "mp",
      "rank": "3",
      "target": ""
    },
    {
      "child": [
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "child": [
            {
              "id": "test",
              "Menutext": "test",
              "node": "td.aqi.test",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "id": "test2",
              "Menutext": "test2",
              "node": "td.aqi.test2",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "id": "test3",
              "Menutext": "test3",
              "node": "td.aqi.test3",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            }
          ],
          "count": 40,
          "id": "aqi",
          "Menutext": "rm",
          "node": "td.aqi",
          "path": "https",
          "rank": "1",
          "target": "embedded"
        }# ,
        # {
        # "count": 40,
        #   "id": "mr",
        #   "Menutext": "mr",
        #   "node": "td.mr",
        #   "path": "https",
        #   "rank": "1",
        #   "target": "embedded",
        #   "child": []
        # }
      ],
      "count": 9,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "td",
      "Menutext": "TD",
      "node": "td",
      "path": "/poter/td",
      "rank": "4",
      "target": ""
    },
    {
      "child": [
        {
          "body": "toggle",
          "child": [
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 54,
              "id": "deku",
              "Menutext": "deku",
              "node": "rep.ops.deku",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "1",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 55,
              "id": "kalo",
              "Menutext": "kalo",
              "node": "rep.ops.kalo",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "2",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 56,
              "id": "aa",
              "Menutext": "aa",
              "node": "rep.ops.aa",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "3",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "body": "toggle",
              "count": 57,
              "id": "himi",
              "Menutext": "himi",
              "node": "rep.ops.himi",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "4",
              "target": "embedded"
            },
            {
              "id": "baku",
              "Menutext": "baku",
              "node": "reports.ops.baku",
              "path": "https",
              "rank": "5",
              "target": "embedded"
            }
          ],
          "count": 53,
          "id": "ops",
          "Menutext": "ps",
          "node": "rep.ops",
          "path": "/poter/rep/ps",
          "rank": "1",
          "target": ""
        }
      ],
      "count": 13,
      "header": "root",
      "id": "rep",
      "Menutext": "rep",
      "node": "rep",
      "path": "/poter/rep",
      "rank": "11",
      "target": ""
    }
  ]
}

Code:
def extract(data, query):
    return {
        "menustructure": extract_nodes(
            data["menustructure"], [x.split(".") for x in query]
        )
    }


def matches(name, query):
    name = name.split(".")

    for q in query:
        size = min(len(q), len(name))
        print(size)
        if name[:size] == q[:size]:
            print(name[:size], q[:size])
            return True

    return False


def extract_nodes(data, query):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        data = [
            extract_nodes(x, query)
            for x in data
            if matches(x["node"], query)
        ]
        return [x for x in data if x is not None]

    if isinstance(data, dict) and matches(data["node"], query):
        if "child" in data:
            children = extract_nodes(data["child"], query)
            # print(children)
            if len(children) != len(data["child"]):
                print()
                data = data.copy()  # copy-on-write
                data["child"] = children
            if not data["child"]:
                return None
        return data

Input I'm passing:
print(extract(data, ["td.aqi.test2"]))

here you can see I'm passing td.aqi.test2 as I need json of only this part but as aqi is the only child in td , it returns all the child of aqi and not just test2.
But if we uncomment the commented part in masterjson and run the code it works as intended.
Note: I cant make some big change in code or replace the code with something new until there is no way as this code is not working for this special case only.

If extract_nodes you have (in part):
...
            children = extract_nodes(data["child"], query)
            # print(children)
            if len(children) != len(data["child"]):
                print()
                data = data.copy()  # copy-on-write
                data["child"] = children
...

You are comparing the number of children returned from the call to extract_nodes with the number of children passed to it and only then making and updating a copy of the data node (a dict instance) being processed. You need to do this copy unconditionally.
Update: Also, some nodes have no "child" key implying that the node has no children while other nodes have a "child" key whose value is am empty list, also implying no children. You should be treating both of these cases identically, but you are only currently checking to see if the key exists or not. If the key exists, you need to also see if its value is an empty list:
Your extract_nodes method should be:
def extract_nodes(data, query):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        data = [
            extract_nodes(x, query)
            for x in data
            if matches(x["node"], query)
        ]
        return [x for x in data if x is not None]

    # If we come here then data must be a dict instance.
    if matches(data["node"], query):
        # Treat missing "child" key and empty "child" list the same:
        children = data.get("child", [])
        if children:
            children = extract_nodes(children, query)
            if not children:
                return None
            data = data.copy()  # copy-on-write
            data["child"] = children
        return data

NOTE (Updated): If you specify as your query a non existent path such as ["td.aqi.x"] where node "td.aqi" exits but "td.aqi.x" does not, the question becomes what do we want to return. If non-existent paths will never be queried, then the above code suffices. Otherwise, there are 3 options as I see it. Read the comments in the following code:
def extract_nodes(data, query):
    """Return tree that matches the query."""

    OPTION = 3  # See the options described below

    # Suppose the input represents a tree with the following nodes:
    #               "a"
    #               |
    #             "a.b"
    #             /   \
    #       "a.b.c"  "a.b.d"
    #           /        \
    #     "a.b.c.1"   "a.b.d.1"
    #
    # Then if the query is "a.b.c", we will return the subtree containing the
    # matched node ("a.b.c") and any children it might have, i.e.:
    #
    #               "a"
    #               |
    #             "a.b"
    #             /
    #       "a.b.c"
    #           /        \
    #     "a.b.c.1"
    #
    # But what if we specify a path that does not exist, such as "a.b.c.d"?
    # What should we return? There are 3 options:
    # OPTION = 1: Nothing, since this query cannot be completely matched.
    # OPTION = 2: The longest substree we can match, but with none of its children,
    #             i,e, "a" -> "a.b" -> "a.b.c"
    # OPTION = 3: The longest substree we can match with all of its children,
    #             i,e, "a" -> "a.b" -> "a.b.c" -> "a.b.c.1"
    #
    # Set OPTION above to 1, 2, or 3 accordingly.

    if isinstance(data, list):
        data = [
            extract_nodes(x, query)
            for x in data
            if matches(x["node"], query)
        ]
        return [x for x in data if x is not None]

    # If we come here then data must be a dict instance.
    if matches(data["node"], query):
        # Treat missing "child" key and empty "child" list the same:
        children = data.get("child", [])
        if children:
            extracted_children = extract_nodes(children, query)
            if not extracted_children:
                # Could not completely match the query:
                if OPTION == 1:
                    return None
                if OPTION == 3:
                    extracted_children = children
            data = data.copy()  # copy-on-write
            data["child"] = extracted_children
        return data


Thanks for you response, It's working fine but if i pass all nodes from master json, it only returns 3 menus and not all,
basically this based on role if i pass root that means it will return complete json because in root all nodes are available in menu list [],  in extract function query is list of nodes that user have access for. so in case of Admin role user have access for all the menus so based on on query list it should return all menus.

I'm not following what you are saying. It seems like you now have a new problem. It would be useful for you to provide the input (what you are passing to extract), what you are expecting as the result and what result you actually get. Also, your question has nothing to do with JSON. You may be creating data by loading a JSON string, but once you have done so you are working with a dict instance and it's irrelevant how it was created (for example, you could have used pickle instead of JSON). Function extract also returns a dict instance and not a JSON string.

data["menustructure"] is  list of 10 dict instances, each one representing a tree and therefore you have 10 roots. You seem to be using "root" in a different way and that's why in part I am not understanding what you are asking. If you wanted to be able to match all 10 trees, then they should be the children of a single node named, for example, "root". Then all of its children would have node names that begin with "root."

My bad, this is a example input in extract method ["Admin.configuration.c", "Admin.configuration.d", "dc", "td.aqi.test3"] as query,
Now what it means by this input is  user have access to all these menus , now If I'm admin this list will have all the nodes present in menustructure as access work based on nodes in query list, Now whats happening after making the change in extract_nodes you suggested , If i give someone admin access he is not getting output as intended.

You still aren't explicitly stating what you precisely expect and what you are actually getting. When I try passing your list ["Admin.configuration.c", "Admin.configuration.d", "dc", "td.aqi.test3"] as the query I get three trees back but am missing the tree whose root node name is "dc". Are you getting the same result and are all 4 trees what you expect?

I have updated extract_nodes. Let me know if that gives you what you want. Otherwise, I have no idea what you expect (see previous comment and respond).

this is input for admin user
['Admin.configuration.a', 'Admin.configuration.b',
'Admin.configuration.c', 'Admin.configuration.d', 'Admin.roles', 'Admin.menu', 'Admin.rmm',
'Admin.userroles', 'Admin.logs', 'l.Tickets', 'testingk', 'td.aqi.test',
'td.aqi.test2', 'td.aqi.test3', 'td.mr', 'rep.ops.deku',
'rep.ops.kalo', 'rep.ops.aa', 'rep.ops.himi', 'reports.ops.baku']
so basically if this list is passed code should return the complete json, which is happening with the old code but after making the change in extract_nodes , for the admin users it returned some of the menu not all.

Have you tested with the latest version? You have in your data "node": "reports.ops.baku", and I think it should be "node": "rep.ops.baku",

It won't return the complete set of trees (please stop saying "json"). For example, your query does not contain "dc" among others.

I have updated the Note and its corresponding code. This points out that your original code did not handle invalid queries consistently. For example, if you specified a query for a node that does not exist, e.g. "dc.a", it would return nothing if node "dc" had children or "dc" if node "dc" had no children. Again, if invalid queries will never occur, you can ignore this.
